# Debug nested WebLogic artifact

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I'm trying to debug my maven project deployed on WebLogic. The maven module is not directly deployed on the container, but there is another maven module, which only contain the weblogic-application.xml and the only things necessary for the project to be deployed on WebLogic.

However, it seems to be a problem, when it comes to debugging. I have the Java options for debugging set and with fiddling around some options, I even managed to get a tick above the breakpoint in IntelliJ, however I could never get it to actually stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: Probably your source code is out of synch with the ear/war you deploy. Try to add the source to your project. Sorry but I don't use InteliJ.